# How to use the MuPDF library to open pdf files when a pdf file is opened from webview

Tags: android, webview, mupdf

I made a demo app with the MuPDF library but it opens one pdf file, from the device storage, when the app is opened. I made another app using webview to open htmls from the assets folder. And I want to use the library to open a reader whenever the button I linked to a pdf file is clicked. I could not find any tutorials regarding this and I would really appreciate any help.

MainActivity.java for webview application:

```
package epsnotes.com.epsnotes;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView mywebView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mywebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mywebView.canGoBack())  {
        mywebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

activity_main.xml for webview app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="epsnotes.com.epsnotes.MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java for MuPDF Demo app:

```
package yoseman.com.mupdfdemo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.artifex.mupdfdemo.FilePicker;
import com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore;
import com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFPageAdapter;
import com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFReaderView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

    MuPDFCore core = null;
    try {
        core = new MuPDFCore(this, "/storage/emulated/0/Download/AMHMOE11.pdf");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MuPDFReaderView reader = new MuPDFReaderView(this);
    reader.setAdapter(new MuPDFPageAdapter(this, new FilePicker.FilePickerSupport() {
        @Override
        public void performPickFor(FilePicker filePicker) {

        }
    }, core));
    layout.addView(reader);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml for MuPDF Demo app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="yoseman.com.mupdfdemo.MainActivity">


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If the PDF is not on the device, download the PDF using your favorite HTTP client API (e.g., `HttpUrlConnection`, OkHttp), then view it.

Comment: I have the pdf in the app's assets folder along with the htmls I am using in webview. I have linked a button to a pdf but when I run the app and tap on it, nothing happens. I want MuPDF to open a reader when I tap on the button.

Comment: @Yoseph Mandefro: please show code how you implemented it so far.

Comment: @user2281606 I added the code. If you have any questions about my question, please ask. I appreciate your concern.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT - Start:**

To get the file name in Java, pass name with a JavascriptInterface.
Define your Interface-Class (inside MainActivity).

```
public static class PdfJavascriptInterface {

    WeakReference<MainActivity> mainActivity;

    public PdfJavascriptInterface (MainActivity mainactivity) {

        this.mainActivity = new WeakReference<>(mainActivity)
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void passPdfFileName(String name) {
        if (this.mainActivity.get() != null) {

             this.mainActivity.get().loadPdf(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Add a JavascriptInterface to your webView:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new PdfJavascriptInterface(this), "Android");
```

After that, implement loadPdf method (inside MainActivity).

```
public void loadPdf (String name) {

    try {

        InputStream pdfStream = this.getAssets().open(name);
        //MuPDFCore class has two constructors:
        // 1. MuPDFCore(Context context, String filename) 
        // 2. MuPDFCore(Context context, byte buffer[], String magic)
        // this time we take nr. two. Because of that you need byte array
        // i wrote it down quickly, no good style here :-)
       ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       while (true) {
           int read = pdfStream .read(buffer);
           if (read  == -1) break;
           bos.write(buffer, 0, read);
       }

       final byte[] pdfByteArray = bos.toByteArray(); 

       //i will not rewrite render method, thats your task :-)
       new Thread(new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {

               render (..., pdfByteArray, ...);
               // in render method
               // core = new MuPDFCore(context.getApplicationContext(), 
               // pdfByteArray, null);
           }
       }).start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Afterwards, implement a javascript method, getting invoked on a onClick event:

```
function passPdfFileToJava(name) {
    if (typeof Android != "undefined"){ 
        if (Android.passPdfFileName!= "undefined") {
            Android.passPdfFileName(name);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT - End**

I do not use MuPDFReaderView at all, i insert the rendered image in my own layout. 
Because of that, i do not know if it is a suitable solution for you.

1.) Render pdf in appropriate dimensions:

```
/**
* renders PDF file, start this method on a worker thread
* @param callback Callback is a interface implemented by your activity
* @param context Context
* @param pathToPdfFile String
* @param width int 
* @param height int
*/
public void render (Callback renderCallback, Context context, String pathToPdfFile, int width, int height) {

    MuPDFCore core;
    try {
        //do not use hardcoded paths ("/storage/emulated/0/Download/)
        // use something like
        //Environment
        //.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
        //.getAbsolutePath() + 
        //File.separator + 
        //"AMHMOE11.pdf"          
        core = new MuPDFCore(context.getApplicationContext(), pathToPdfFile);  

        //Assuming here you are in portrait mode: height is the longer value of 
        //DisplayMetrics.widthPixels and DisplayMetrics.heightPixels
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
        // you want to render whole page, patches == 0
        core.drawPage(bm, width, height, 0, 0, width, height, core.new Cookie());
        core.onDestroy();
        callback.rendered(bm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}


public interface Callback {

    public void rendered (Bitmap bm);
}
```

2.) Stuff rendered Bitmap into ImageView:

XML (activity_xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/main_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="yoseman.com.mupdfdemo.MainActivity">

  <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/pdf_bitmap"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java (MainActivity.java):

```
@Override
public void rendered (final Bitmap bm) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {


            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.pdf_bitmap);
            imageView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(MainActivity.this.getResources(), bm));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So the PDF will open in the new layout. The path to one specific PDF has to be set for the layout to open it, that's the problem. There are multiple PDFs in my webview htmls. I want one PDF to open when the html bbutton for it is tapped. Any solution is suitable for me as long as it gets the job done.

Comment: "The path to one specific PDF has to be set for the layout to open it, that's the problem. There are multiple PDFs in my webview htmls." I do not understand that...where are your PDF files, local or server? Are you linking with a-href in HTML to PDF files?

Comment: Local, the PDF files are in the assets folder along with the htmls for webview. I am actually using a web builder, and I linked different buttons to different PDFs. I'm sure it's using a-href.

Comment: <a class="mbr-buttons__btn btn btn-lg btn-default animated fadeInUp delay" href="AMHMOE11.pdf">AMHARIC</a>

Comment: I will copy the codes to the project and will get back to you with the results.